# Why can't Coraline's real parents remember the trap?

Tags: plot-explanation, coraline

So I learnt many things about [***Coraline***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0327597/) from ["The Hidden Meaning of the Movie “Coraline”](http://vigilantcitizen.com/moviesandtv/hidden-meaning-movie-coraline/)

Basically it looks like a normal fantasy animation movie, but it actually has a deeper meaning. It interprets the procedure of mind control for leaving pain. An alternate reality that provides so much comfortableness that one simply just ignores reality and wants to live in that world.

But the 'other mother' from Coraline's alternate reality is a witch who wants to trap her forever.

Each time Coraline went to that alternate world she remembers everything. How she went, what she has done, the beauty, the horror. At a point, "other mother" trapped Coraline's parent using the same way she provoked Coraline to enter in her world (using dolls). Then Coraline rescued her parents through some events, but her parents can't remember what happened? Question is why not?

If Coraline can remember everything why can't they? What's the hidden meaning of it from the viewpoint of mind control? Coraline even saw snow in their hair and jacket, so it wasn't a dream. They were actually trapped in the alternate reality. They wrote "HELP US" inside the mirror. Still they can't remember anything. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It wasn't explained in the film, nor is it explained in the source novel (except to say that it's *not explained*)

> *CORALINE’S PARENTS NEVER SEEMED to remember anything about their time
>   in the snow globe. At least, they never said anything about it, and
>   Coraline never mentioned it to them.*
>
> *Sometimes she wondered whether they had ever noticed that they had
>   lost two days in the real world, and came to the eventual conclusion
>   that they had not. Then again, there are some people who keep track of
>   every day and every hour, and there are people who don’t, and
>   Coraline’s parents were solidly in the second camp.*

Answer (score 3):

I think that maybe since adults were raised to stop believing in things like the Beldam or "other mother", so they think it was just a dream, but coraline still believed in things like the Beldam, so she knew it wasn't a dream

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is related to the idea that kid's minds are more imaginative then adult. Ghost in movies generally are seen by children and not by adults because the **children are more open to other ideas.**

Answer (score 0):

my opinion might not make sense but this is it. I read one of the answers to this comment and it said " there are people who keep track of every day and every hour, and there are people who don't" this lead me to believe that once the parents escaped their adult side kicked in and they realized that they had stuff to do which is why the parents were i think making dinner or something, but deep down they knew she did something right which is why Coraline's mother gave her a smile when she saw her. I'm not 100% positive that this is correct, but it is all that i can come up with.

Answer (score -1):

I really love the film Coraline and think she is still trapped in the other world ever since the first visit. I mean how could the other mother put her back without anyone noticing and it's strange how the door to the other world loses its magic the other mother blocked the exit in and out. Also, it's weird how the acrobats downstairs have a magical item that conveniently helps to find the ghost eyes also the real mother got her the gloves. That is why at the end of the movie the other mother's face is the garden and not Coraline's and also explains where the cat went it went to the real world. She is still stuck and will always be stuck there Coraline's parents are probably long gone and she is still trapped.

Or her mother might have ignored the fact that all that happened and that is why she got the gloves she was not allowed to. She did not want to say it was all real because it would scar Coraline for life and she did not want that.

Comment: An interesting fan-theory, but not one that is backed up by the film or the source novel. -1 from me, I'm afraid.